# excel vba how to use countif across worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function, countif

I want to count how many numbers is `>=40` in `Worksheets(1)`

this is my code but it will not work:

```
Sub Overall_Pass()

    Worksheets(2).Range("B1").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets(1).Range("N2:N296"), ">=40")

End Sub
```

can anyone help me pls?

Comment: Everything is fine. The result is in cell **B1** in Worksheet(**2**).

Comment: OP, you are going to need to elaborate on "not working" since @VBasic2008 is right as this does work. Have you verified that your range is actually filled with numbers instead of text values masquerading as numbers?

Comment: @urdearboy I think i know what's wrong with the code because the numbers in the selected range are in percentage and i didn't put a "%" behind 40 ._.

Comment: So you want >=.40 then

Comment: @urdearboy i edited it to ">=40%" and it works